# JetBrains NuGet packages have no output

Tags: c#, nuget, jetbrains-ide

I was looking for ways to make memory and performance measurements on customer machines without installing additional software on said machines. I stumbled upon the JetBrains command line tools. From the description I gathered I can just add the NuGet Packages to my software, write a small dialog that sends commands to a console and then transfer the results home to analyse properly with the Desktop Versions of dotMemory and dotTrace.

These are the NuGet packages:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.dotTrace.CommandLineTools.windows-x64/2023.2.2
https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.dotMemory.Console.windows-x64/2023.3.0-eap01

I installed the packages and rebuild the projects. But no assemblies are getting copied to output. My first thought was the packages are not properly installed and checked the csproj. But there they are.

```
<PackageReference Include="JetBrains.dotMemory.Console.windows-x64" Version="2023.2.2" />

<PackageReference Include="JetBrains.dotTrace.CommandLineTools.windows-x64" Version="2023.2.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Why have a NuGet Package that does not provide any useable assemblies? Am I supposed to find out which assemblies from the package I need and copy them myself using a "<files include=..." Tag? Why have a NuGet at all then? And what exactly is the "PrivateAssets/IncludeAssets" doing here? I thought that was for test purposes while developing a package ?

Comment: *"Why have a NuGet Package that does not provide any useable assemblies"* - have you make sure the package you installed compatible with whatever .net version your project is? also, i checked the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Performance_Profiling__Profiling_Using_the_Command_Line.html) it ask you to run a `dotnet` command not chugging it on some app.

Comment: Yes I read the docs. There is no compability with .NET. You send a command to a console. this can be done from any .NET app. This works perfectly fine if I extract the dll by hand and add it to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't copied to the output folder because there is a scenario when users want to use these tools to profile their application ocasionally but don't want to include them in their product. Therefore, files from Nuget are placed in "Tools" folder where they can be accessed when needed.
If you want to include them in your application, you have to do it yourself to get them into the final product.
Or, as an alternative, you can use another product "[Self Profiling API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Profiler.SelfApi)", it is designed exactly for this scenario, but could be a little complicated to manage.

Comment: Aha! Thank you! I had not encountered a NuGet package that works like this before. Interesting option